# Tess4j separate pages from pdf with multiple pages in Java Application

Tags: java, ocr, tesseract, tess4j

I have added Tess4j to my Java Application everything works great my PDF document with more than 50 pages is properly recognized and read and written to a text document as a string.

The problem is how can I mark end of each single page from my PDF file in my text document? By for example special string like ("++##- END--##++") which does not occur on the pages of PDF document???

Is this even possible with Tess4j?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you use `createDocuments` method or the low-level `TessBoxTextRenderer` API, the output text file will contain page-separator characters, which are FF by default.

https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/FAQ.html#what-page-separators-are-used-in-txt-output-by-tesseract-400

http://tess4j.sourceforge.net/docs

Comment: Thanks, I split the PDF document into individual pages using PdfBoxUtilities.splitPdf(); After that I processed each individual page Tess4j normally. 

http://tess4j.sourceforge.net/docs/docs-4.4/net/sourceforge/tess4j/util/PdfBoxUtilities.html#splitPdf(java.io.File,java.io.File,int,int)